# SearchBar filtering and adapting the UITableView cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

My aim is to filter tableview's cells using search bar. The point is i have a button in a custom cell, this button is whether hidden or not it is added to list on the right(this is another uiview)

For instance, i have added one cell using plus button to the right and hide plus button, and filtered using search bar. When i filtered for the cell i have added, it should come with hidden plus button. Since it is already added before filtering.

I have written some code to textDidChange method of the searchBar but still could not do it.

How to achieve this goal?

My tryout code;

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{


        NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells];

    for (DoctorListCell *cell in cells)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell: %d",cell.plusButton.tag);

        if(cell.plusButton.tag==0)
        {
                            [cell.plusButton setHidden:YES];

                            [tableView reloadData];
        }

    }

if(text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = TRUE;
    filteredListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (PlannedCustomer* docs in doctorsTable)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [docs.customerName rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredListContent addObject:docs];
        }
    }
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: why you are setting hidden property of plus button here.. And using reloadData twice.. Dint get you. Please explain some more..

Comment: here, i tried if a filtered content is a data source, set the cell that have hidden button stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set hidden property of cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method after filtering the cells from your filtered list. Or you can set hidden in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

**UPDATED:**

If your plus button is a subview then override then set the hidden property in some method in your custom cell class. And then call that method.

Or you can just remove the plus button instead of hiding.

For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *nib;
    static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *theCell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if([theCell.contentView subviews]){
        for(UIView *view in [theCell.contentView subviews]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if(theCell== nil)
    {
        nib  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your custom cell name" owner:self options:nil]; 
        theCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        theCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[theCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
if(yourcondition)
//hide button
else
//show button
}
```

Comment: i did, now when i cancel the filter cell which are added to right should come with hidden buttons, but they again come with buttons. i need to save cells with its state and properties but how?

Comment: that NSARRAY one where you are enumerating the array to set hidden property. And is this plus button a subview or accesssoryView?

Comment: this plus button is the subview of the custom tableview cell

Comment: Did you get any help??